# TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to code a function that triggers when a user gets a new comment and sends a notification.Comments are stored in /Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}. Users save their device notification tokens to /users/{userID}

```
    'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotif = functions.firestore.document('Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}')
.onWrite((change,context) =>
{
    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

    return admin.firestore().collection('Users').document(user_id).collection('Notifications').document(notification_id).get().then(queryResult=>{

      const from_user_id = queryResult.data().From;

      const from_data = admin.firestore().collection('Users').document(from_user_id).get();
      const to_data = admin.firestore().collection('Users').document(user_id).get();

      return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result => {

        const from_name = result[0].data().From;
        const to_name = result[1].data().From;

        console.log("FROM: " + from_name + "TO: " + to_name);

      });

    });

});
```

And here's the package.json file. Everything is up-to-date

```
 {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


    {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Firebase gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
at Promise.all.then.result (/user_code/index.js:21:47)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: Your code consistently uses `From` (with a capital `F`), while the error message mentions `from` (with a lowercase `f`). Are you sure this is the code that raises the error?

Comment: I tried with both the cases of F. The error corresponds to "From" if with capital F and "from" if with f.

Comment: It looks like the `from_data = admin.firestore().collection('Users').document(from_user_id).get()` document does not exist. You'll want to check `if (from_data.exists) ` before calling `from_data.data()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the length of your array (result). You should log result.

```
 return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result => {
    console.log(result);

    const from_name = result[0].data().From;
    const to_name = result[1].data().From;

    console.log("FROM: " + from_name + "TO: " + to_name);

  });
```